# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java

вылазит ошибка, не могу понять, почему происходит зацикливание, может сможете объяснить простым языком

```
class External {
    External() { };
    External iext = new External(){ };
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        External ext = new External();
    }
}
```

Comment: п. 1. Внутри объекта создаётся объект того же типа, в котором см. п. 1

Answer (score 2):

Внутри `External` создаётся объект `External`, внутри которого создаётся объект `External`, который опять же, создаёт внутри ещё один объект `External`... И так до бесконечности. В итоге получаем переполнение стека.

```
class External {
    External() { };
    External iext = new External(){ }; // Вот тут проблема!
}
```

Comment: тогда почему, если сделать так

    static External iext = new External(){ };

то ошибки не будет

Comment: @Alkon потому, что если сделать так как вы говорите `static External iext = new External(){ };`, то вы создаёте статический объект. Он в другой области видимости... По этому и нет ошибки.

Comment: еще с интерфейсом не разобрался, как код правильно вставлять

Comment: и как вставить перевод строки. ппц интерфейс у сайта