# статическая переменная с типом класса

Tags: java

```
class External {
    External() { };
    static int aaa = 7;
    static External tt = new External();

}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        External ext = new External();
        System.out.println(ext.tt);
        System.out.println(ext.tt.tt);
        System.out.println(ext.tt.aaa);
        System.out.println(ext.tt.tt.aaa);

    }
}
```

вывод у программы будет
External@3feba861
External@3feba861
7
7

Однако если убрать static из объявления переменной tt то возникнет ошибка stackoverflow.
Почему не возникает ошибка при статичной переменной, если там также идет зацикливание вызова, т.е. код
System.out.println(ext.tt.tt.tt.tt.tt.tt.tt.tt.tt.tt.tt.tt.aaa);
так же выдаст 7.
В чем отличие объявления статической и не статической переменной с тем же типом, что и сам класс. Уже башку всю сломал.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1087405/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-stackoverflowerror)

Comment: можете дать норм статью про объявление статичных переменных с типом класса

Comment: Первая же ссылка в гугле: https://javarush.ru/quests/lectures/questsyntax.level06.lecture06

Comment: там не то абсолютно

Answer (score 1):

Просто получить статическое поле можно как и через класс `External.tt` так и через объект класса:

```
External ext = new External();
ext.tt;
```

Так вот если в `External.tt.tt.tt` первый раз к полю `tt` идёт обращение через класс, то последующие обращения `.tt` происходят через объект класса `External` (всё время через один и тот же). Естественно, так как `tt` - `static`, то происходит создание только **одного** объекта на класс, поле `tt` инициализируется только один раз, все `tt` тут один и тот же объект:

```
System.out.println(External.tt == External.tt.tt); // true - ссылки одинаковые, 
                                                   // что значит, что это один и тот же объект
```

Никакой рекурсии тут нет.

Comment: спасибо, буду подробнее изучать, как данные в стеке хранятся